# Format multilevel group_by in R

Tags: r

In R, when I run this group_by code, I obtain this result.

```
df <- tibble(y=c('a','a','a', 'b','b','b','b','b'), z=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2))
df %>% group_by(z,y) %>% summarise(n())

z   y   n()
1   a   3
1   b   3
2   b   2
```

Is there a way to make it look like this?

```
z   y   n()
1   a   3
    b   3
2   b   2
```

My goal is to have the formatting look the way it does in Pandas, where the multilevel index isn't repeated each time ( see below ).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possibility:

```
df <- tibble(y=c('a','a','a', 'b','b','b','b','b','a','b'), z=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3))

df2 <- 
  df %>% 
  group_by(z,y) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  group_by(z) %>% 
  mutate(z2 = if_else(row_number() == 1, as.character(z), " "), y, n) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  transmute(z = z2, y, n)

df2 %>% 
  knitr::kable()
```

I'm having trouble thinking of ways to do this that don't involve grouping by the `z` column and finding the first row. Unfortunately that means you need to add a couple steps, because a grouping variable can't be modified in the `mutate` call.